# How to pass a variable from PHP to LESS?

Tags: php, variables, less

I use PHP (lessphp) to compile LESS files into CSS files on the serverside. I would like to pass a variable to the LESS file, like a color or a language:

```
compile('input.less?lang=en')
```

and use it as a variable in LESS like @lang.

Is this possible? If not, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a built in feature of [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/), here's the documentation: http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#setting_variables_from_php

Answer (score 3):

I don't know less or lessphp so this may not be helpful and you may have already looked at it, but on the site I notice someone else has asked the same question and there are a couple of responses:

http://leafo.net/lessphp/#dsq-comment-132897969   (You'll have to wait for it to load the comments from disqus)

It looks like Nico-B has developed a patch to do this: https://github.com/Nico-B/lessphp/commit/aacc195fff4ec0075226a29bc832de371a8001ce#diff-1

Comment: Sounds like a solution, we'll look into it. Thanks!